# swift - how can i check if a specific viewController is the previous viewController

Tags: ios, swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

I am trying to detect if my previous viewController is one specific and if it is when i press back it will load the tabBar controller.
I am changing view controllers with revealViewController
here is my code :
here i save the previous view controller:

```
let newVC = 
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
storyboardIdentifiers.newViewControllerID) as! newViewController         
newVC.previousVC = self
self.revealViewController().setFront(newVC, animated: true)
```

this is my back action where i need to check if previous is the first viewController

```
func backAction() {
let first  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardIdentifiers.firstViewControllerID) as! firstViewController
let second = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardIdentifiers.secondViewControllerID) as! secondViewController

if previousVC  ==  first || previousVC == second {
            previousVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardIdentifiers.revealViewControllerID) as! SWRevealViewController
self.revealViewController().setFront(previousVC, animated: true) 
}
else {
 self.revealViewController().setFront(previousVC, animated: true)
}
```

but when i press back it doesn't detect that it is from one of these view controllers.

when i print "self" it gives me this result

```
<MyPackege.firstViewController: 0x7f9e80f2b5a0>
```

but it doesn't load the TabBarController

Comment: can you please elaborate ? " if my previous viewController is one specific " then what do you want to do ? load that same VC or else load another one ?

Comment: I want to load the previous one but load it with the TabBarController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `==` operator try using  `isKind(of: )` method to check the type of viewcontroller

```
func backAction() {
let first  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardIdentifiers.firstViewControllerID) as! firstViewController
let second = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardIdentifiers.secondViewControllerID) as! secondViewController

if previousVC.isKind(of:firstViewController ) || previousVC.isKind(of:secondViewController ) {
            previousVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardIdentifiers.revealViewControllerID) as! SWRevealViewController
self.revealViewController().setFront(previousVC, animated: true) 
}
else {
 self.revealViewController().setFront(previousVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It Worked perfect!

Comment: It would be great if you could accept this as the answer so that it may help others too